# Create document if it does not exist in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

the goal is to allow the creation of documents only if a document with the same id does not exists.

```
match /{AppNode}/Documents/BlueBooks/{bookId} {

     function isUniqueBlueBook() {
      return !exists(/databases/$(database)/Main/Documents/BlueBooks/$(request.resource.id));
    }

   allow create: if isUniqueBlueBook();

}
```

this fails with the following error

```
false for 'update' @ L5, Service call error. Function: [exists], Argument: [path_value {
  segments {
    simple: "databases"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "(default)"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "Main"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "Documents"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "BlueBooks"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "123"
  }
}
```

EDIT: The function exists should not fail if a document does not exists. Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Your `isUniqueBlueBook` has `main` as one of the segments in the file to check, while the error message has `RezVip3` as the corresponding segment. Check which of the paths is correct.

Comment: Also, as long as the id is generated automatically by your firebase sdk, I think the chances of collision is very little (and I personally ignore it).

Comment: I tried to edit out RezVip3 and replaced it with Main .... but forgot to double check. the error is still present

Comment: Are you sure of your path? It does not match with the `match` statement above...

Comment: the function exists should return true or false this one errors out.

Comment: The path you pass looks invalid to me, that's why it throws an error

Comment: can you please explain why the path is invalid ?